# When to use ASP.NET validation controls and when not to use?

Tags: asp.net

I am a beginner in ASP.NET programming, and my question is regarding built in validation controls provided by ASP.NET.

Can any one brief me the pros and cons of using ASP.NET validation controls ? Does in cause any performance penalty when it is used in production application?

Answer (score 1):

Validations controls are excellent resource because they can provide both client side and server side validations. They are easy to use, flexible and offer consistence interface.

On downside, the markup size rendered by validation controls is just too much - so having many validation controls will increase your page size. It would be great if js related to validation controls could have packaged as a separate js file. I believe that few third party libraries do exists for validations that offer same benefit w/o above mentioned downside.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the above answer, also understand that even if you have validation control which can allow you to validate on client, it would be important to revalidate on the server side as well.

In fact some architects do recommend to validate at the business layer as well.